# error code 516 while writing to file in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, file-io

I am getting this error while writing to a file in my iPad. But the same application works fine in the simulator. I am attaching the code here.

```
    NSString *filepath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:doc.contentStreamFileName];
                         NSFileManager *fMngr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
                         if ([fMngr fileExistsAtPath:filepath]) {
                             NSLog(@"File already available");
                             CMISExtensionElement *elem = [doc.properties.extensions objectAtIndex:0];
                             NSString *description = [self crop:elem.description];
                             [self loadImage:doc.contentStreamFileName desc:description];
                         }
                         else{
                             [doc downloadContentToFile:filepath completionBlock:^(NSError *error){
                                 if (nil == error) {
                                     NSLog(@"successful");
                                 }
                                 else
                                 {
                                     UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error retriving content" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error code: %d",error.code] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                     [alert show];

                                 }
                             }progressBlock:^(unsigned long long bytesDownloaded, unsigned long long bytesTotal){
                                 if (bytesTotal == bytesDownloaded) {
                                     CMISExtensionElement *elem = [doc.properties.extensions objectAtIndex:0];
                                     NSString *description = [self crop:elem.description];
                                     [self loadImage:doc.contentStreamFileName desc:description];
                                 }
                             }];
                         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't try to write within the application's bundle directory.

You should probably be using the NSApplicationSupport directory if the files are produced and consumed by your app, and the NSApplicationDocuments directory if you want the files to be visible to the user.

its not strictly necessary, but its common practice to create a subdirectory within that for your files, as well. You an use NSFileManager's createDirectory... method for that.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered writing to the app Documents directory instead? I don't think you're supposed to write to the application bundle, only read from it.

```
NSString *documentsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:doc.contentStreamFileName];
```